# How can I get the name of functions dynamically

Tags: python

I can put `those about to be executed functions` in to functions_results.

I get print out the results, but I couldn't get the functions itself name.

For example,

```
functions_results = [
    schedules(),
    schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01"),
]

list_of_functions_heads = [x for x in functions_results]
for i in list_of_functions_heads:
    # this is what I want to get
    # print(i.FUNCTION_NAME) # 'schedules()'

    print(i.head())
```

## **name** not work in my case

> print(i.**name**)

```
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: You already called the `schedules` function, so you cannot get the name of the function object.. What does `schedules()` return at all to have a `.head()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can access this through `function.__name__`.

Comment: __name__ not work in my case, pls see my updatem thanks

Comment: This is because `i` is not a function in your code.  `i` is `schedules()` or `schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01")`, which going by your Error message, seem to be `DataFrame` objects.  You need to make sure your object is actually a function if you want to use `__name__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__name__` attribute to get your function name :

Example :

```
>>> def my_func():
...   print 'my_func'
... 
>>> my_func.__name__
'my_func'
```

Read more about python modules https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules

Also note that since you have called your function within `functions_results` :

```
functions_results = [
    schedules(),
              ^ #here you called the function 
    schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01"),
]
```

So you can not get its name in your loop. for example if in preceding example we want to get the name of function after call python will raise an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> my_func().__name__
my_func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>>
```

So for getting ride of this problem you need to put the function without calling it in your list :

```
functions_results = [
    schedules, 
    schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01"),
]
```

Also note that you can not do it again for second function call :

```
schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01")
```

and for getting ride of this problem too you can use `hasattr(obj, '__call__')` method (and `callable` in python3 )to check if `i` was a function type then get its name :

```
for i in list_of_functions_heads:
      if hasattr(i, '__call__'):
           print i.__name__
```

Comment: __name__ not work in my case, pls see my updatem thanks

Comment: @user3675188 Did you have read my answer completely?I explained that you shouldn't call your function and use `hasattr` in your loop

Comment: yes, i tried, but `schedules("2014-06-01", "2015-03-01")` how could I avoid it be called in my method, thanks

Comment: @user3675188 As I said for avoid that use `hasattr`

Answer (score 0):

access this through `function.__name__.`

```
>>> def a():
...     pass
... 
>>> a.__name__
'a'
>>>
```